# Regex to find substring between 2 Strings excluding a specific String

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, regex-group, regex-negation

I have checked all the existing questions on Stackoverflow but I couldn't find the perfect answer to it and need your help.

So basically I have multiple Strings containing different formats of URL in different ways, for eg:-

1:

`<p><a href='https://abcd.com/sites/WG-ProductManagementTeam/FunctionalSpecs/Forms/AllItems.aspx?id=/sites/WG-ProductManagementTeam/FunctionalSpecs/DevDOC/Enhancements to PA Peer Checklist/PA Peer Checklist (V2.3) -v10.0.pdf&amp;parent=/sites/WG-ProductManagementTeam/FunctionalSpecs/DevDOC/Enhancements to PA Peer Checklist&amp;p=true&amp;ga=1'>WG-Product Management Team - PA Peer Checklist (V2.3) -v10.0.pdf - All Documents (sharepoint.com)</a></p>`

2:

`https://abcd.com/sites/WG-ProductManagementTeam/FunctionalSpecs/Forms/AllItems.aspx?id=%2Fsites%2FWG%2DProductManagementTeam%2FFunctionalSpecs%2FDevDOC%2FEnhancements%20to%20PA%20Peer%20Checklist%2FPA%20Peer%20Checklist%20%28V2%2E3%29%20%2Dv10%2E0%2Epdf&parent=%2Fsites%2FWG%2DProductManagementTeam%2FFunctionalSpecs%2FDevDOC%2FEnhancements%20to%20PA%20Peer%20Checklist&p=true&ga=1`

3:

`https://abcd.com/:b:/r/sites/WG-ProductManagementTeam/FunctionalSpecs/DevDOC/Enhancements%20to%20PA%20Peer%20Checklist/PA%20Peer%20Checklist%20(v2.0)%20-%20v3.0.pdf?csf=1&web=1&e=txs2Yq`

I want to extract a part of URL like this:-
/DevDOC/....../.pdf

as you can see above shared 3 URL strings are all different but I am not able to find the most efficient way to resolve this.

I need to do it in such a way that it works for every type of URL string even though formats are different it should extract it from any and every String in same way.

Right now I am using regex: ".*/FunctionalSpecs(?!.*\1)(.*?)(.pdf)" and it is working for URL 2 and 3 shared above but in case of URL 1 it is returning:

/DevDOC/Enhancements to PA Peer Checklist&p=true&ga=1'>WG-Product Management Team - PA Peer Checklist (V2.3) -v10.0.pdf

which is incorrect, I wanted this:

/DevDOC/Enhancements to PA Peer Checklist/PA Peer Checklist (V2.3) -v10.0.pdf

Please help me resolve this as soon as possible as It seems so easy but I am not able to do it in an efficient way.

Also, I am trying to do it in Java.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can either decode and then use:

```
 `/DevDOC/[^\.]+\.pdf`
```

Or without decoding you might want to use:

```
DevDoc[^\.]+pdf
```

I'm relying here on the existence of a period before the `.pdf`, as the regex should keep going until first appearance of a period. If that doesn't work you might want to use `[^"]+`.

Comment: I tried both but it is not working, it is not what I was looking for.
Though thanks for your time and help.

Comment: I got one that's working:
(DevDOC[^=]+Enhancements.*?pdf)

Comment: Thanks for your time and reply but this also doesnt work in all cases so what I did was is just fetched the link in href when there were multiple .pdf and atleast 1 href in string and for all the other cases my previous regex was working so used that.

Thanks, I really appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use decodeURIComponent to decode your url and then you can extract your value like below.

```
var url = decodeURIComponent("your encoded url string");
console.log(url.match(/DevDOC[\s\S]*\.pdf/i));
```

Comment: Not working, I get this output:

DevDOC/Enhancements to PA Peer Checklist/PA Peer Checklist (V2.3) -v10.0pdf&parent=/sites/WG-ProductManagementTeam/FunctionalSpecs/DevDOC/Enhancements to PA Peer Checklist&p=true&ga=1">WG-Product Management Team - PA Peer Checklist (V2.3) -v10.0.pdf

what I want is this: 

DevDOC/Enhancements to PA Peer Checklist/PA Peer Checklist (V2.3) -v10.0pdf


Thanks for reply.

Comment: you may add **FunctionalSpecs** in REGEX to filter your desired  string as below

`url.match(/FunctionalSpecs\/DevDOC[\s\S]*\.pdf/i)`

Comment: I did and tried in multiple ways but it didnt work like I wanted to but no worries, I used my previous regex for all other cases and just made new regex to fetch link in href when there were multiple .pdf and atleast 1 href in string so this way it is working perfectly for all cases now.

Thank you for your time and help, I really appreciate it.